# [__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting JSON data from an API and display it in a tableView. When user scrolls at the last row, the next page will be added to the current data. 
But I am getting this error when next page data is added.

[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

```
    func loadUser(_ currentPage:Int=1){
        APIService.loadUser(currentPage, size: 100, callback: { data in
            if let data = data["user"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
               self.jsonData?.append(contentsOf: data
               self.tableView.reloadData()
               self.hideLoadingInView(view: self.view)
            }
        })
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.jsonData?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell") as! UserTableViewCell
        cell.user = self.jsonData?[indexPath.row]
        if !isLoading && (indexPath.row == self.jsonData!.count - 1){
           currentPage += 1
           loadUser(currentPage)
        }
       return cell
    }
```

Comment: Do not do this. Do not attempt to load data from the `cellForRowAt` method. That's a really, really bad idea. That method should do one and only one thing - return the requested cell. Cells can be requested at any time in any order.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest few potential fixes:

1. Add Exception Breakpoint to your project, so you can better debug your particular issue. It's very useful tip: https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/ You'll probably find out what's wrong with this.
2. Move the UI manipulation inside the API call response into the `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` block, to be sure the UI is manipulated on the main thread. Otherwise it can cause weird behavior and maybe also your issue.
3. Move the check if you need to fetch another page from API to the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function. Some people do recommend to do it in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegated method of `UIScrollView`.

Then it will look like this.

```
func loadUser(_ currentPage:Int=1){
    APIService.loadUser(currentPage, size: 100, callback: { data in
        if let data = data["user"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.jsonData?.append(contentsOf: data)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.hideLoadingInView(view: self.view)
            }
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.jsonData?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !isLoading && (indexPath.row == self.jsonData!.count - 1){
        currentPage += 1
        loadUser(currentPage)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell") as! UserTableViewCell
    cell.user = self.jsonData?[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```